# Are local variables in the Arm Cortex architecture stored in registers or the stack?

Tags: c, arm, embedded

I remember going through some disassembly of a simple arm example and the locals seemed to be stored in `registers` rather then on the `stack`. Is this always true for arm?

Comment: How about a hundred of locals? Seems unlikely....

Comment: Given a sane compiler and ABI, it's normally true for just about anything that has general-purpose registers. That's kinda the point of them...

Comment: What if you need to take an address of the variable?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Then the variable will be put on the stack for when you take the address of it.  Do remember, however, that the local variable only exists while you are in the scope of its declaration.  That address is no longer valid once you leave scope.

Comment: @SouravGhosh:  The compiler will manage the local variable set and cycle variables in and out of the registers as needed.   Some variables will only exist in registers (particularly if they're just intermediate values in a calculation).   Others need to exist temporarily on the stack, but it's all driven by the code written and the processor architecture and function calling conventions.   The compiler guarantees correctness, though not necessarily performance.

Comment: @RussSchultz: That's why the question is too broad.

Answer (score 4):

One, or the other, or both.  Depends on types, values, number, size, architecture, register count, registers free, phase of moon, what side of bed Jon Skeet got out of this morning.

Comment: One of the question I'm not sure if I should upvote (for being correct) or downvote (for not being helpful).

Comment: I forget 'calling convention' :(

Comment: You forgot a lot of things, e.g. if OP was born under Jupiter ascending, lived once on Gallifrey (hopefully not - no offence), etc.

Answer (score 3):

The storage of local variables is a matter for the compiler rather then the processor architecture specifically.  Moreover it will more likely use register storage when complier optimisation is enabled.

Any compiler is likely to do that on any architecture, but compared to say x86, ARM has a larger and more orthogonal register set, so you are more likely to observe register storage in ARM code perhaps.

Of course, the stack will still be used when there are a large number of variables and for larger aggregate types.  The optimiser will analyse the code flow and select which variables are likely to be best stored in registers for optimum performance.